# Right to left isolate string. C++

Tags: c++, unicode, farsi

does anyone have experience in Unicodes?

I am facing a tough problem with Farsi unicodes.
I have an `std::wstring s = (L"\u0634\u0646\u0628\u0647");` which is a Farsi word. When I debug it, I see that the underlying word is exactly what I want, but reversed. So I have researched and found that u2067 is for right to left reading the string.
NOTE:

> I cannot reverse the string manually because Farsi characters are changing their shape regardless of their position in the string.

So I added the 2067 int the beginning and got
 `std::wstring s = (L"\u2067\u0634\u0646\u0628\u0647");`.
But now the underlying string is the same , just added a square in the beginning if the string instead of reversing.
Does anyone have experince with this stuff? Please suggest a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Is this a problem just in the debugger? The string of course has 4 characters, the first of which is \u0634. RTL merely is an instruction to a Unicode output system that it should render the first character on the right, and then to the left. If the debugger renders each character individually, that doesn't help you. RTL rendering depends on a text renderer working on a whole string.

Comment: This works fine in Visual Studio 17 debugger, Windows 10 `OutputDebugString(L"\u0634\u0646\u0628\u0647\n")` The output is supposed to be `L"شنبه"` - It is displayed with `\u0634` appearing on the right side.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani interesting, I wonder how it knows to do that.  Maybe it (or an underlying Windows API) inspects the contents of the string.

Comment: @PaulSanders Yes, Windows draw functions know if the code point starts from left to right, or has other odd properties not present in Latin characters. This is also exposed in `ScriptString` or `DirectWrite` for anybody brave enough to tackle it directly.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani ok, thanks.  I guess it has to be that.  Just goes to show that Windows is not the complete crock that many people make it out to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underlying string will be the same. You haven't changed the order of bytes, which is written right there in the code. But a renderer that understands Unicode should take those bytes and display the *characters* right-to-left. That's a visual thing. It has nothing to do with the encoding. From your question, it's not entirely clear what else you expected. It may be that you are viewing the string in a debugger, and the debugger does not support this feature of Unicode. If you try outputting the string to a proper console you ought to see it as you expect.